# Xamarin: Activity works when used as main activity, crashes when called as intent

Tags: android, layout, android-intent, crash, xamarin

I have an Activity that will create a canvas and capture a signature drawn on it and save it. It works fine as a stand alone Activity. The problem is when I try to call it as an Intent from another Activity it crashes when trying to load.

Here is the AXML from the signature capture code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF888888">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/acceptbtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/acceptbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pleasesigntext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pleasesign" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I set ids for the main LinearLayout and Buttons and the TextView.

Here is the code for the Activity

```
public partial class SigCapMainActivity : Activity
{
    static LinearLayout mContent;
    SignatureView mSignature;
    static Bitmap mBitmap;

    public const int SIGNATURE_ACTIVITY = 72;
    static Button cancelButton,
                  resetButton,
                  acceptButton;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainSigCapLayout);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        cancelButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cancel);
        resetButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.reset);
        acceptButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.acceptbtn);
        acceptButton.Enabled = false;

        acceptButton.Click += acceptButton_Click;
        resetButton.Click += resetButton_Click;
        cancelButton.Click += cancelButton_Click;

        mContent = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainlayout);

        mSignature = new SignatureView(this, null);
        mSignature.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        mContent.AddView(mSignature, WindowManagerLayoutParams.FillParent, 100);
   }
}
```

You see I SetContentView and then I set the variables for the Buttons. mContent is set to the main LinearLayout and then the SignatureView (custom view) is added to the main LinearLayout.

This works properly when I run it as the main Activity.

However, if I call this as an Intent from a different Activity

```
    void releaseFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SignatureCapture.SigCapMainActivity));
        StartActivityForResult(intent, SignatureCapture.SigCapMainActivity.SIGNATURE_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

SigCapMainActivity crashes in OnCreate when it gets to the

```
mContent = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainlayout);
```

line. The FindViewById crashes because for some reason it's bringing the mainlayout as a Button type rather than a LinearLayout type.

Please help me figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Assigning the value returned by FindViewById<> to a static property might not be good idea... What's your use case for this?

Comment: I'll try changing them from static properties, however, the Button objects are also static and they don't have any issues. It's just when I try to read the mainlayout where I get the error showing up.